# Jquery not found in modal the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I make the call from a modal Bootstrap by clicking on a button , my problem is that the second time is called modal , jquery goes down and disappears my datetimepicker, thanks for your help

Comment: Please add some more details - a fiddle/plunker or some code

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="example">Fecha Dep&oacute;sito:</label>
                        <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fecha_deposito" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false,
            maxDate: moment()
       });

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, in the firts time the modal show the datatimepicker, but in the second time the jquery not found and dissapears the datatimepicker.

Comment: It can not be possible that jquery not found on second time. You are doing something wrong. Please share me some more details. The second time click function or something.

Comment: Is the second time called the function and the created the modal, You think you may be due to problems with the libraries ?                           <link rel="stylesheet" href="../componentes/bootstrap/core/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../componentes/bootstrap/core/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../componentes/bootstrap/plugins/datatimepicker/3.1.3/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />  <script type="text/javascript" src="../componentes/jquery/core/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: It is very difficult to understand this way. Can you please create a plunker/jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry Im not understand, I that is not "plunker/jsfiddle", in my console show: "TypeError: e.handler.apply is not a function      jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4:8496"

Comment: Well plunker/jsfiddle are online tools that provide run-time environments for your application. All I need is your code with me. So that I can debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this line to your dialog call:

```
$(this).dialog('destroy').hide()
```